# Deleting / removing geometry with sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, geometry

With sculpting I can deform the geometry nicely, especially when using the dyntopo feature.

How can i delete geometry like cutting a hole into a sculpted box, or cut open a sculpted torus to make it a C shape instead of a O shape ?

Currently I would go back to layout mode and do it by polygon-editing and then return to sculpting,

Is that the right way to do it?

[image: delete geometry with sculpting]

Comment: Probably there is no better way, than do it in Edit Mode.

Comment: thanks!  i feel less stupid doing this now.